# set user id based on pk when logged in through facebook

Tags: facebook, yii

I am able to login/logout on my web app using facebook. But the problem is when the user needs to update his profile on my application, he can't. It would say that he is restricted to view his own page. The only way for this to happen is that user identity is probably not set. But I am not sure how to correct this. When I tried `Yii::app()->user->user_id` the Id is actually correct id, which is the pk in user model. So how is it that he cannot get to update his own page?

in my facebookUserIdentity:

```
    public function authenticate() 
        {
            if($this->getIsAccessTokenValid() && $this->setFBUser())
            {
                $this->_user = $this->getUserFromDatabase();
                if($this->_user === false)
                    return false;

                $this->setState('isUser', false);
                $this->setState('isAdmin', false);
                $this->setState('isShop', false);
                $this->setState('isSuper', false);
                $this->setState('user',$this->_user);

                $this->_id = $this->_FBUser['id'];
//I've tried doing something like $this->_id = Yii::app()->user->user_id; or like $this->_user->user_id; ?
                $this->_name = $this->_FBUser['name'];

                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

getting user from db:

```
protected function getUserFromDatabase()
    {
        $FBUser = $this->_FBUser;

        if($FBUser)
        {
            $user = User::model()->findByAttributes (array('oauth_uid'=>$FBUser['id']));
            if(!$user)
            {
                $user = new User;
                $user->oauth_uid = $FBUser['id'];
                $user->username = $FBUser['id'];
                $user->first_name = $FBUser['first_name'];
              //other info etc

                $user->image = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $FBUser['id'] . "/picture?type=large";
            }
            else 
            {
                if ($user->oauth_permission == 'n')
                {
                    $this->errorMessage = self::ERROR_LOGIN_DISABLE;
                    return false;
                }
                $user->last_login_date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }
            if($user->save())
            {
                return $user;
            }
            else 
                $this->errorMessage = CJSON::encode ( $user->getErrors());
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $this->errorMessage = "Failed getting facebook user data";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and lastly, the controller page rules:

```
public function accessRules()
{
$params=array();
$id=Yii::app()->request->getParam('id'); 
$params['model']=$this->loadModel($id);
return array(
    //stuff
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
'actions'=>array('create','update','RemoveImage'),
'roles'=>array('admin','super','owner'=>$params),
),
    //stuff
```